# Will these instructions create this binary tree?

Tags: computer-science, binary-tree

Hi I'd really appreciate if anyone could confirm if these instructions

[image: http://www.cowsgomoo.uni.cc/fail.png] http://www.cowsgomoo.uni.cc/fail.png

Will produce this answer :

```
            t
      /          \
   u              V
  / \           /   \
w     x        y     z
```

Comment: Those are not instructions. It is a memory dump.

Comment: @user551841 you should work a little and copy the complete questions here. If the link vanish your question is more nonsensical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you got it right. V is the parent node of Z. (It is a weird question)

Comment: 7= 2* 3+ 1 ... What is weird??

Comment: The 50, 51, 52, ... series is just decoration.